# Валидация формы при помощи replace

Tags: javascript

Удаляю из поля input ненужные символы так:

```js
$(document).on('input','#num',function() {
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d\.]/ig,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="num">
```

Но так любое изменение в поле сбрасывает курсор в конец. Здесь можно чего-нибудь придумать или нужен другой подход?

Comment: `type="number"`

Comment: @Grundy, А если валидация будет нужна на что-то другое?

Comment: @Other, очевидно тогда надо будет отдельно смотреть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же вставляете новое значение, вот и перебрасывает.
Можно заморочится с определением позиции курсора, бубен достать, но правильнее всего просто определять левый символ при вводе и не давать его вводить:

```js
$(document).on('keydown','#num',function(e) {
  // Проверка на длину необходима для того, чтобы допускать действие спец. клавиш типа стрелок
  if(e.key.length === 1 && /\D/.test(e.key)) return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="num">
```